# Spring Security configuration based on different http methods

Tags: java, spring, spring-security, spring-security-oauth2

In my Spring Boot application I have configured following OAuth2 `ResourceServer`:

```
@Override
public void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
    // @formatter:off
    http
            .antMatcher("/api/**").authorizeRequests()
            .antMatchers("/api/v1.0/users").permitAll()
            .anyRequest().authenticated()
            .and()
            .csrf().disable()
            .sessionManagement().sessionCreationPolicy(STATELESS); 
    // @formatter:on
}
```

In my REST API `UserController` I have two different request handler methods - for POST and for GET http methods. Right now both of them in the configuration above are public.

I'd like to secure POST method and make a GET as public even for anonymous users

How the configuration above can be changed in order to support this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just add the method in the matcher

```
antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/api/v1.0/users")
```